# Nginx : UTF-8 charset instead of ISO-8859-1

Tags: php, nginx, character-encoding, php-5.3, iso-8859-1

I want my Nginx output ISO-8859-1 and not UTF-8 :

```
#curl -I www.xyz.com
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx
Date: Fri, 26 Feb 2016 15:36:47 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.10-1ubuntu3.21
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
```

I had this in my conf :

```
server {
  ...
  charset iso-8859-1;
  ...
}
```

I tried to put it in my etc/nginx/nginx.conf, in my etc/nginx/site-enabled/app.conf, almost in every place I can but no luck...

This is my locale :

```
#locale
LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="fr_FR.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have no idea on what to do next...

*NB : I work on a docker container to replicate an old server running PHP5.3 because I need REGISTER_GLOBAL..*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the charset is already defined in the Content-Type header by PHP, Nginx default behaviour is to not touch the charset. To change this behaviour you would have to set the [override_charset](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_charset_module.html#override_charset) directive to "on".

I'm assuming you haven't tried this, but you should rather set the [default_charset](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.default-charset) in your php.ini to the charset you want, instead of converting it with Nginx.

Comment: Omg, thanks to point this to me. I built my docker container from an other container, which was also from an other container... which has a custom.ini in /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d with default_charset = "UTF-8"...

Answer (score 1):

Check if your PHP script is *not* explicitly outputting a `charset` attribute. If not, then I guess that the default PHP configuration in Ubuntu (it *is* the default in Debian) is to add the UTF-8 charset, and from now on you can only change it in nginx by setting up a conversion table to go back from UTF-8 to ISO-8859-1 again, which is a waste (and takes time to setup).

So basically, you have <s>three</s> two options:

1. Change your script to add a `charset=iso-8859-1` attribute explicitly in the `Content-type` header.
2. Change your `default_charset` option in `php.ini`. This, however, will change the default character in *all* PHP scripts run by your nginx servers (i.e. you'd better know what are you doing).
3. <s>Change the default charset only in the FPM block used by your ISO-8859-1 server. This can be accomplished by adding the following line to your FPM configuration block: `fastcgi_param PHP_ADMIN_VALUE "default_charset=iso-8859-1";`</s>

*EDIT*: In the end, option 3 actually will set `default_charset` on PHP-FPM as they're scheduled for your server, *and the option will stick*, so it's pretty much the same as 2, only more unpredictable.

Comment: Actually, third option is quite viable, as it allows to set encoding to a single website server from docker container. It adds a layer of inconvenience to editing `php.ini`, but worked great for me as I had to write custom config for nginx and adding another parameter into `fastcgi_params` was not difficult at all. Just to explain my case a bit more, I had an old site encoded in `windows-1251` and had to serve it as `utf-8`. And by default both nginx and php nowadays think they serve utf-8. Thanks.